# Echonest :: song duration

Tags: python, echonest

I want my `Echonest` `response` to get `song duration`, which is supposed to be part of the `audio_summary`.

```
params = {
        'type':'artist-radio', 
        'artist':artist, 
        'results': 3,
        'bucket' : ['id:spotify-WW', 'tracks'],
        'limit': True
    }
    response = en.get('playlist/static', **params)
    songs = response['songs']
```

so, to get song `duration`, which `key/value` should I use in the example above?

**NOTE**: the wrapper being used is `pyen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duration`is an analysis found in `song/profile`, and not in `playlist/static` method, so we need a second `response` from the `api`.

this is one way of obtaining each song `duration` (as well as printing `artist_name` and `song_title`):

```
    #get 'playlist response'
    response_playlist = en.get('playlist/static', **params)
    song_playlist = response_playlist['songs']

    if len(song_playlist) > 0:

        for i, song in enumerate(song_playlist):
            #we need to track each song id
            song_id = song_playlist[i]['id'] #ok
            #in order to get song 'duration', we need to access 'song/profile response'
            #and pass the id as an argument to 'audio_summary'
            response_profile = en.get('song/profile', id=song_id, bucket="audio_summary")
            song_profile = response_profile['songs']
            dur = song_profile[0]['audio_summary']['duration']      
            print dur                           
            #now we access each song 'foreign_id', which is playable by, say, Spotify 
            for track in song:
                track = song['tracks'][i]
                track_id = track['foreign_id'].replace('-WW', '')           
            print '{0} {2} {1}'.format(i, song['artist_name'], song['title'])
```